# What rules apply for this function result to be always an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

what ( if any ) are the main conditions/rules for function

```
a = (b*c)/(b+c)
```

to be true, when using **only** positive integers? This is true:

```
4 = (5*20)/(5+20)
4 = (6*12)/(6+12)
```

Meaning, is there a specific pattern, how the values form?

Comment: Your examples suggest you want $b,c$ to be positive integers (from which it follows that $a$ will also be positive), so perhaps the problem statement should be emended to say so.  Otherwise it's easy to choose $b+c=\pm 1$ and get a different family of results.

Comment: I'm focusing currently only on positive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption $b + c \mid b c$ implies
$$\tag{formula}
\frac{b+c}{\gcd(b+c, b)}
=
\frac{b+c}{\gcd(c, b)} \mid c.
$$
Write $d = \gcd(b, c), b = s d, c = t d$, so that $\gcd(s,t) = 1$.

(formula) yields that $s + t$ divides $c$, and similarly $s + t$ divides $b$. It follows that $s + t$ divides $\gcd(b,c)$.

**This yields the following general construction rule for $b, c$:** take any positive integer $d$, and coprime non-negative integers $s, t$ such that $s + t \mid d$. Define
$$
b = s d, \qquad c = t d,
$$
so that $d = \gcd(b, c)$.

Then
$$
b c = s t d^{2}, \qquad b+c = (s+t) d,
$$
so that $b + c \mid bc$.

The cases listed by OP occur for $d = 5, s = 1, t = 4$, and $d = 6, s= 1, t = 2$. Another example is $d = 5, s = 2, t = 3$, which yields $b = 10, c = 15$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm B=db,&&\rm (B,C) = d\\ \rm C = dc, &&\rm \color{blue}{(b,c)\ =\  1}\end{eqnarray}\rm   \,\Rightarrow\,\  B\!+\!C\mid BC\!\! \overset{cancel \ d\!\!}\iff b\!+\!c\mid \color{#c00}b\,\color{#0a0}c\,d\!\iff\! b+c\mid d\,$ by $\,\begin{eqnarray}\rm (b\!+\!c,\color{#c00}b) = \color{blue}{(c,b)=1}\\ \rm (b\!+\!c,\color{#0a0}c)\, = \color{blue}{(b,c)= 1}\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

$b$ and $c$ must have a common divisor.

Suppose they do not. Then $b+c$ cannot divide b, since c does not divide b, and likewise $b+c$ cannot divide c, since b does not divide c.

edit: per the comments, I should say that $gcd(b,c)>1$ and also that $b|b+c$ and $c|b+c$, as opposed to my comment that $b+c|b$ which is logically impossible since $b+c>b$.

Comment: This is necessary, but not sufficient.  For example, $b=2, c=10$ have a common divisor of 2, but $b+c \not\mid bc$.

Comment: The argument being advanced seems to have a gap.  If $b,c$ are positive, then $b+c$ will not divide $b$ or $c$ regardless of any common divisor between $b$ and $c$.  $b+c$ may of course divide $bc$ without dividing either of the factors individually, as the OP's examples show.